# value is not being assigned to the variable after evaluating the expression

Tags: c++

every time i input in Temp the value of Cel remains zero, why expression is not storing value in it?

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    float Far, Cel, Temp;
    char choice;

    cout << " To convert from Celcius to Farenheit, press 'f' for opposite 'c': "<<endl;
    cin >> choice;

    cout << "Enter Temperature: " << endl;
    cin >> Temp;

    if(choice == 'f' || choice == 'F'){
            Far = (Temp*(9/5))+32;
            cout <<  "Temperature in Farenheit is: " << Far << endl;
    }
    else if(choice == 'c' || choice == 'C'){
            Cel = (Temp - 32) * (5/9);
            cout << "Temperature in Celcius is: " << Cel << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because choice is 'f', or not 'c' ?

Comment: To clarify, `5/9` is `0`, so the whole expression on the RHS of `Cel = ...` evaluates to `0`.

Comment: yes it prints exactly what you've typed

Comment: oh, you mean i shoul do 5.0/9

Comment: For the sake of consistency, 5.0/9.0 would be nicer. For the sake of not repeating yourself, that could be a constant which you reuse.